# Django nested formset without model

Tags: python, django

I have to implement **nested formset in Django, but without model**. The problem is, I don't know how to do it correctly.

I found some solutions for nested formset, but they all use database model:

- https://github.com/nyergler/nested-formset
- https://github.com/Soaa-/django-nested-inlines

The reason I need Django nested formset without model is specific workflow, which must not be changed:

1. first user fills in the form without model behind (I am stuck here with nested formset);
2. posted data are serialized to JSON and encripted;
3. when another user wants to approve this data, data are decripted, deserialized and pre-filled to actual form which uses database model to save data.

The only solution I could find is the following. The scenario is made up (but I have similar scenario). First user have to fill in data about many employees (surname) and their incidents (pairs of date and description).

views.py:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
from functools import partial, wraps
from MultilevelFormset.forms import EmployeeForm

def index(request):
    ffactory = formset_factory(wraps(EmployeeForm)(partial(EmployeeForm, maxsubforms=10)), extra=2)
    formset  = ffactory(request.POST or None, prefix='emp', auto_id=True)

    return render(request, 'MultilevelFormset/index.html', {'formset': formset})
```

forms.py:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
from django import forms
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory

class EmployeeForm(forms.Form):
    surname = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.maxsubforms = kwargs.pop('maxsubforms')
        super(EmployeeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Each employee can have zero or more incidents
        max_incidents = self.maxsubforms
        for i in range(max_incidents):
            self.fields['date_%s' % i] = forms.DateField()
            self.fields['desc_%s' % i] = forms.CharField()
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Django multilevel formset example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}MultilevelFormset/js/jquery.formset.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.employee-container').formset({
                prefix: '{{ formset.prefix }}'
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    {% load my_tags %}

    <form method="post" action="">
        {{ formset.management_form }}

        {% for form in formset %}

            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            <div class="employee-container">
                <h2>Employee</h2>
                Surname: {{ form.surname.errors }}{{ form.surname }}
                <h3>Employee incidents</h3>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Date</td>
                        <td>Description</td>
                    </tr>

                {% for idx in form.maxsubforms|int2rangestr %}
                    {% with attr_date='date_'|add:idx attr_desc='desc_'|add:idx %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ form|getFieldErrors:attr_date }} {{ form|getField:attr_date }}</td>
                        <td>{{ form|getFieldErrors:attr_desc }} {{ form|getField:attr_desc }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endwith %}
                {% endfor %}
                </table>
                <hr />
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my_tags.py:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='getField')
def getField(form, fieldname):
    """Get form field"""
    return form[fieldname]

@register.filter(name='getFieldErrors')
def getFieldErrors(form, fieldname):
    """Get form field errors"""
    return form[fieldname].errors

@register.filter(name='int2rangestr')
def int2rangestr(intval):
    """e.g. return ['0', '1', '2', '3'] for intval=4"""
    lst = []
    for i in range(intval):
        lst.append(str(i))

    return lst
```

Firstly, I tried to create IncidentForm and assign it to form field list "incidents[]", but I was unable to make correct prefixes inside **init** in nested form. So I tried with this approach where nested form fields are like normal fields named date_0, desc0, date_1, desc_1, ... date_n, desc_n. JavaScript would be use to hide fields to user. But this approach doesn't seem right.

My question is: *What is the right way to implement nested formseth without model in Django?*